# Trouble with case-sensitive LDAP user logins to Dovecot

Tags: ldap, dovecot

I asked this to the dovecot list to no avail, so will try here too. Please forgive the crosspost.

I have a client running Dovecot-Postfix on Debian Squeeze. I'm using Dovecot from the Squeeze repository.

```
# dovecot --version
1.2.15
```

I've implemented a central mail_location and am using one vmail user, as I thought this would be be the best approach for when it came time to implement Shared and Public Mailboxes.

```
# dovecot -n
# 1.2.15: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-5-xen-686 i686 Debian 6.0.7 ext3
log_timestamp: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 
protocols: imap imaps pop3s managesieve
listen(default): 127.0.0.1:143
listen(imap): 127.0.0.1:143
listen(pop3): 127.0.0.1:110
listen(managesieve): *
ssl_listen(default): *:993
ssl_listen(imap): *:993
ssl_listen(pop3): *:995
ssl_listen(managesieve): 
ssl_ca_file: /etc/ssl/certs/RapidSSL_CA_bundle.pem
ssl_cert_file: /etc/ssl/certs/mail.example.com.2013.chain.pem
ssl_key_file: /etc/ssl/private/example.2013.key
login_dir: /var/run/dovecot/login
login_executable(default): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
login_executable(imap): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
login_executable(pop3): /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
login_executable(managesieve): /usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve-login
mail_max_userip_connections(default): 40
mail_max_userip_connections(imap): 40
mail_max_userip_connections(pop3): 10
mail_max_userip_connections(managesieve): 10
mail_privileged_group: mail
mail_uid: vmail
mail_gid: vmail
mail_location: maildir:/var/spool/dovecot/%d/%u
mbox_write_locks: fcntl dotlock
mail_executable(default): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
mail_executable(imap): /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
mail_executable(pop3): /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
mail_executable(managesieve): /usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve
mail_plugins(default): quota imap_quota
mail_plugins(imap): quota imap_quota
mail_plugins(pop3): 
mail_plugins(managesieve): 
mail_plugin_dir(default): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/imap
mail_plugin_dir(imap): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/imap
mail_plugin_dir(pop3): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/pop3
mail_plugin_dir(managesieve): /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/managesieve
namespace:
 type: private
 separator: /
 inbox: yes
 list: yes
 subscriptions: yes
lda:
 postmaster_address: postmaster@example.com
 mail_plugins: sieve quota
 log_path: /var/log/dovecot-deliver.log
 info_log_path: /var/log/dovecot-deliver.log
auth default:
 mechanisms: plain login
 passdb:
   driver: ldap
   args: /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf
 userdb:
   driver: ldap
   args: /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-userdb.conf
 socket:
   type: listen
   client:
     path: /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
     mode: 432
     user: postfix
     group: postfix
   master:
     path: /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
     mode: 384
     user: vmail
     group: vmail
plugin:
 quota: maildir:User
 quota_rule: *:storage=1200M
 quota_rule2: Deleted Messages:storage=10%%
 quota_rule3: Deleted Items:storage=10%%
 quota_rule4: Trash:storage=10%%
 sieve: /var/spool/sieve/%d/%u/.dovecot.sieve
 sieve_dir: /var/spool/sieve/%d/%u
```

All of the mail users are LDAP users only (not local UNIX users - not using nsswitch). dovecot-ldap-userdb.conf is a symbolic link to dovecot-ldap.conf

```
# grep -v '^ *\(#.*\)\?$' /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf 
uris = ldaps://mail.example.com/
dn = uid=mail,ou=Services,dc=example,dc=com
dnpass = ******************
tls_require_cert = hard
auth_bind = yes
base = ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
user_attrs = quota=quota_rule=*:storage=%$M
user_filter = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(mail=%u))
pass_attrs = uid=mail,userPassword=password
pass_filter = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(mail=%u))
```

Now, mail addressed to user@example.com and user@EXAMPLE.com correctly gets delivered to the correct mail location of /var/spool/dovecot/example.com/user, but the problem occurs when the user creates their email account in an IMAP client with uppercase characters in their username, e.g. user@exaMPLE.com. **This creates a new directory at /var/spool/dovecot/exaMPLE.com/user, which never receives any mail.** Is it possible to ignore the case the user enters in their mail client and always land them at the lowercase mail directory? Where would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old version of Dovecot, almost three years out of date. I suggest you upgrade to a newer version, 2.2.5 is current. There have been made countless improvements and fixes from which your setup will surely profit.

That said, you should set `auth_username_format = %Lu` in `dovecot.conf` so that Dovecot translates the username to lower case before doing a lookup. This will normalize the usernames to lower case, no matter what the user sets in their mail client.

NB: lower-casing usernames is the default behaviour as of Dovecot 2.1.x.

Comment: Many thanks. I have traditionally tried to stick with what was approved by Debian. While there were features in 2.x that I wanted to use, I wasn't comfortable with the risk of using an unmaintained package. Is that not a wise approach?